# Two color balls and box, draw with replacement only in part of cases

Tags: probability

Suppose there is a box with *N* balls, *k* white and *(N-k)* black. We draw two balls, one after the other. Thus, 4 possible cases are possible: (white, white), (white, black), (black, white), (black, black).

1. (white, white) – in each of two draws, balls are replaced. For *N* balls (*k* white, *(N-k)* black): $$P(white \wedge white) = {\left(\frac{k}{N}\right)}^2$$
2. (white, black) – the special case, discussed later.
3. (black, white) – in each of two draws, balls are replaced. For *N* balls (*k* white, *(N-k)* black): $$P(black \wedge white) = \frac{N-k}{N} \frac{k}{N}$$
4. (black, black) – in each of two draws, balls are replaced. For *N* balls (*k* white, *(N-k)* black) probability of the event is: $$P(black \wedge black) = {\left(\frac{N-k}{N}\right)}^2$$

For the case 2. – (white, black) – **black ball is not returned**. It works like if white ball would "allocate" next black ball preventing its return to box. (The white ball is still replaced, of course).

Also: **white balls are replaced, but the experiment stops if *k* white balls (i.e. all) have been drawn** in any of the 4 configurations.

***Question***: how many the special (white, black) events are expected to occur? The experiment obviously stopps after whichever comes first:

- drawing white ball *k* times (in any of the 4 configurations),
- moving all *(N-k)* black balls outside box.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the first time around P(white^black) is also (N-k)k/(N)$^2$ but after the white black sequence there are still k white ball but only N-k-1 black balls.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: yes exactly

Comment: This is an interesting problem.  I will try to work it out.  But given that I am busy someone else will probably beat me to it.

Comment: @Calkin This is all interesting as far as understanding why the urn works the way it does.  But the problem is already well-defined mathematically,  So it is just a matter of look at the possibilities and drop blacks for subsequent probability calculations based on the W B pair occurring.